# CSV file into list

Tags: python

I have a file with a 4 entries on each line.

```
Monday, Ben, 255, c
Tuesday, Sam, 237, r
etc...
```

I need to create each entry into a list so I can individually reference each value. However if the file is changed it still needs to work. I basically need to be able to display lines that are c or r depending on user input.

```
def loadnames():
    names = open("names.csv")
    nameList = names.readlines()
    namelistLen = len(nameList)
    inlistList = []
    for i in range(namelistLen):
        inlistList.append([])
        inlistList[i].append(nameList[i])
        print(inlistList[i])

    print(inlistList[1])


loadnames()
```

This is what I have done so far and it does create a new list for each entry but the whole entry is one value. How can I make it so the commas dictate the values?

Comment: Did you try simply searching for "Python CSV"? There's a whole module in the standard library for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the *split* function for text, but your example is better served by the csv module.

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvread = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in csvread:
            print row
            #or do other stuff with row
```